# Tmux does not work in ZSH shell in arch linux

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, tmux, archlinux

Initially, I had tmux working in bash shell.  Then, I installed the zsh shell and changed the default shell to zsh with the following line:

`#set shell`
`set-option -g default-shell /usr/bin/zsh`

Then, I noticed that tmux would not work.  For instance, after getting into tmux, pressing `ctrl+b+"` displayed a yellow bar at the bottom with "index" on it.

Since then, I have made several modifications to tmux.conf and now I do not know the settings for the default tmux.conf. I tried removing and reinstalling tmux but the tmux.conf file still remains the same.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install tmux using this command: 
`dpkg --purge tmux` 
 This will erase all tmux configuration file. And then install it again
`apt-get install tmux`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am using arch linux and dpkg command is not found. I did try `sudo pacman -Rsc tmux` and it still does not get rid of the current tmux.conf file.

Comment: Try deleting the config files at the paths mentioned by the wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmux#Configuration    
The config files are not owned by the package and are therfore not removed by `pacman -Rsc`